# Postgresql "update query returning *" with limit

Tags: database, postgresql, jdbc, limit

Can I run an update query with return clause and also limit the rows returned? For example I run an udate query and it updates a million records, but I dont want to get the updated million rows back to result set.. just a sample say 1000 records. Is this possible?

My Query :

```
UPDATE table1 SET col1 = value1 RETURNING *
```

I want to get the number of columns updated and a sample 1000 rows after update.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
with updated as (
  update the_table_with_many_rows
     set some_column = 42
  where ...
  returning *
)
select u.*, 
       count(*) over () as total_update_count
from updated as u
limit 1000;
```

Comment: Thanks for you answer. Also, can you please let me know if it is possible to get the total count of rows updated along with (select with limit) ??

Comment: @ShannuVaddi: see my edit. It is not considered very polite to change or extend the question after you have an answer. Your initial question should have contained  that requirement already

Comment: Ok. I am new to ask questions on stackoverflow. I changed with an intention of giving more information. By the way, thanks for the updated answer.

Answer (score 3):

You can do this with a [CTE](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/queries-with.html):

```
WITH updates AS (
  UPDATE my_table SET (f1, f2, f3) = (v1, v2, v3)
  WHERE some_condition
  RETURNING *)
SELECT * FROM updates
LIMIT 1000;
```

However, you have no control over which 1,000 rows will be returned, unless you can use some ordering in the outer query.

Comment: Thanks for you answer. Also, can you please let me know if it is possible to get the total count of rows updated along with (select with limit) ??